# How to backup media without logging into the phone?

Tags: adb, backup, locked-out

The screen of my phone is not responding. I tried to restart the phone but this didn't correct the problem. Now, I can't access it, and log in to my phone, so I probably need to take the phone to the SAT. But maybe, I will lost all my photos, videos and music.

My phone is not rooted, and I have not installed Helium or Titanium Backup. So, is there any way to backup all files of my phone, without be logged in with ADB?

Comment: I don't know what's SAT? Which device and Android version are you using?

Comment: If you can't unlock the phone using the touch screen, you might be able to do it using an USB mouse connected to an USB on-the-go connector. If your phone supports USB OTG, a cursor will appear that you can use to control the device.